# Cannot invoke method with an argument list of generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generic-programming

I have `ListDataSource`which manages all model lists `ListDataModel`below:

```
protocol Serializable {} // Empty protocol

protocol AncestorListDataModel {}

protocol ListDataModel: AncestorListDataModel {
  associatedtype T: Serializable
  var items: [T] { get }
}

class BaseListDataModel<T>: ListDataModel where T: Serializable {
  ...
}

class BaseListDataSource: NSObject {
  private var listModels: [String: AncestorListDataModel] = [:]
  private(set) var modelMapping: [String: Serializable.Type] = [:]
  ...

  func getModel<T>(of type: T.Type, at index: Int) -> T? where T: Serializable {
    if let models = self.listModels[String(describing: T.self)] as? BaseListDataModel<T> {
        if index < 0 && index >= models.items.count {
            return nil
        }

        return models.items[index]
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Assume I have

```
class Person: Serializable {}
```

I call `BaseListDataSource` somewhere like

```
let dataSource = BaseListDataSource()
...

// Retrieve meta class type Person
if let personType = dataSource.modelMapping("Person") {
  // I want to get the first Person element in the Person list which I stored in dataSource
  let person = dataSource.getModel(of: personType, at: 0)
}
```

I get an error 
`Cannot invoke 'getModel' with an argument list of type '(of: Serializable.Type, at: Int)'`.
Is there a way in Swift to pass a class type to method `getModel(of:_at:_)`like above?

Update: I found a way to change my code in my answer and I edited question code syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It took several days for me to think about this issue and finally I found a way to change as below:

```
protocol Serializable {} // Empty protocol

protocol AncestorListDataModel {
  func getGeneric(at index: Int) -> Serializable?
}

protocol ListDataModel: AncestorListDataModel {
  associatedtype T: Serializable
  var items: [T] { get }
}

extension ListDataModel {
  func getGeneric(at index: Int) -> Serializable? {
    if index >= 0 && index < items.count {
        return items[index]
    }

    return nil
  }
}

class BaseListDataModel<T>: ListDataModel where T: Serializable {
  ...
}

class BaseListDataSource: NSObject {
  private var listModels: [String: AncestorListDataModel] = [:]
  private(set) var modelMapping: [String: Serializable.Type] = [:]
  ...

  func getModel(of type: String, at index: Int) -> Serializable? {
    if let models = self.listModels[type] as? AncestorListDataModel {
        return models.getGeneric(at: index)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

And somewhere I need to get an element of type Person in a ListDataModel

```
let dataSource = BaseListDataSource()
...

// Retrieve meta class type Person
if let personType = dataSource.modelMapping("Person") {
  // I want to get the first Person element in the Person list which I stored in dataSource
  let person = dataSource.getModel(of: String(describing: personType), at: 0) as! Person
}
```

My idea is creating a protocol called AncestorListDataModel with a mandatory method getGeneric(at:_) which returns an instance that conforms to Serializable, and ListDataModel has to inherit it. Then I have to cast this instance to a type I want to use.